# How to show data correctly in Line Chart using React-Chartjs-2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, linechart, react-chartjs

I'm using react-chartjs-2 to make some charts, I'm trying to make a line chart where the y-axis is a number and the x-axis is a date. The problem I'm having is that the y-axis data isn't plotting correctly.

[image: line_chart]

The data should be plotted in date order, but as you can see in the image, the x-axis date order is wrong. The data that is graphed comes from a matrix, to be specific, the data that is shown in the image is the data of "Last 30 days":

```
[
    {
        "Last 7 days": {
            "Diesel": [
                {
                    "fecha_crea": "2023-12-25",
                    "sum_cant_consumo": 50,
                    "fuel_type": "Diesel"
                }
            ],
            "Gasolina": [
                {
                    "fecha_crea": "2023-12-20",
                    "sum_cant_consumo": 50,
                    "fuel_type": "Gasolina"
                },
                {
                    "fecha_crea": "2023-12-25",
                    "sum_cant_consumo": 100,
                    "fuel_type": "Gasolina"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Last 30 days": {
            "Diesel": [
                {
                    "fecha_crea": "2023-11-25",
                    "sum_cant_consumo": 20,
                    "fuel_type": "Diesel"
                },
                {
                    "fecha_crea": "2023-12-01",
                    "sum_cant_consumo": 160,
                    "fuel_type": "Diesel"
                },
                {
                    "fecha_crea": "2023-12-15",
                    "sum_cant_consumo": 20,
                    "fuel_type": "Diesel"
                },
                {
                    "fecha_crea": "2023-12-25",
                    "sum_cant_consumo": 50,
                    "fuel_type": "Diesel"
                }
            ],
            "Gasolina": [
                {
                    "fecha_crea": "2023-11-25",
                    "sum_cant_consumo": 100,
                    "fuel_type": "Gasolina"
                },
                {
                    "fecha_crea": "2023-12-10",
                    "sum_cant_consumo": 7,
                    "fuel_type": "Gasolina"
                },
                {
                    "fecha_crea": "2023-12-20",
                    "sum_cant_consumo": 50,
                    "fuel_type": "Gasolina"
                },
                {
                    "fecha_crea": "2023-12-25",
                    "sum_cant_consumo": 100,
                    "fuel_type": "Gasolina"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

The data is organized in this block of code:

```
// Group the data by fuel_type for each "label"
            const transformedData = groupedDataByRangeC.map(({ label, data }) => {
                const groupedData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                    const { fuel_type, ...rest } = curr;

                    if (!acc[fuel_type]) {
                        acc[fuel_type] = [];
                    }

                    acc[tipo_combustible].push({ fuel_type, ...rest });
                    return acc;
                }, {});

                // Sort the data arrays for each fuel_type by date
                Object.values(groupedData).forEach((array) => {
                    array.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.fecha_crea) - new Date(b.fecha_crea));
                });

                return {
                    [label]: groupedData
                };
            });
```

And the chart is show the data in this block of code:

```
const getLineChartData = () => {
        const selectedDataObject = transformData.find((data) => data[selectedData]);
        if (selectedDataObject) {
            return Object.entries(selectedDataObject[selectedData]).map(([fuel_type, data], index) => ({
                label: fuel_type,
                data: data.map((item) => ({
                    x: item.fecha_crea,
                    y: item.sum_cant_consumo,
                })),
                borderColor: predefinedColors[index % predefinedColors.length],
            }));
        }
        return [];
    };
```

I don't really know why the chart doesn't show the x-axis data based on date if in the array the data is sorted by oldest to newest date. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your x axis seems to be a [category axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html), that means the strings in `fecha_crea` are treated as just strings, not parsed as dates, which means they are always placed at equal distance regardless of the date difference and not sorted. To start working with [time axes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html), that reflect the actual dates, you should set your chart's `options.scales.x.type: "time"` and follow the other requirements typically expressed as error messages.

Answer (score 0):

As @kikon comment indicates, the x-axis data is a string but should be a date. To solve my problem I just installed this npm package: 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns' and imported it to the component: `import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';`, register "TimeScale" in the "Chart.js":

```
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    BarElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    Filler,
    ArcElement,
    LineElement,
    TimeScale,
} from 'chart.js';

ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    BarElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    Filler,
    ArcElement,
    LineElement,
    TimeScale,
);
```

set the chart options this way:

```
const chartOptions = {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    tooltipFormat: 'MMM do',
                    unit: 'day',
                    displayFormats: {
                        day: 'MMM do ',
                        month: 'MMM do ',
                        year: 'MMM do ',
                    },
                },
                ticks: {
                    maxTicksLimit: 15,
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Register date',
                },
            },
            y: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Total Gallons',
                },
            },
        },
    };
```